# Is there a command to stop xmrig that runs in background?

Tags: linux, xmrig

I haven't found any such command among the listed in the output of `xmrig -h`. I run the miner with `"background": true` in `config.json`.

As my `xmrig` is started in the background by a script that
makes sure that my miner runs all the time in the background
I need to know a command that gracefully exits the miner, under certain conditions included in the script.
If there is such a command I would then add it to my script so that my miner can be stopped automatically.
Because of the above reasons managing `xmrig` via `tmux` does
not solve the problem, at least I can't see a way in which I can script starting and stopping `xmrig` with `tmux`.

Comment: pkill xmrig  ?? (-9 to be nasty about it, if pkill supports -9)  There was a small program ttyecho which can pipe/send commands into a tty. Would have to run ttyecho as root/sudo

Comment: Scripting tmux is easy. Start xmrig in a named window, and kill-window the named window to kill it.

Answer (score 4):

I've created a systemd unit file for xmrig: [Command line options](https://xmrig.com/docs/miner/command-line-options)

nano /etc/systemd/system/xmrig.service

```
[Unit]
Description=XMRig Daemon
After=network.target
    
[Service]
User=user
Group=user
Type=simple
ExecStart=/home/user/xmrig/xmrig --config=/home/user/xmrig/config.json
Restart=always
    
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Update systemd configuration and enable xmrig for system startup:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl enable xmrig.service
```

start, stop, status as usual:

```
systemctl start xmrig.service
systemctl status xmrig.service
systemctl stop xmrig.service
```

Comment: You should remove `--background` (because you've used `Type=simple`), and remove `StandardOutput=null`, `StandardError=null`, so you can read the output/log messages with `journalctl`. Lastly, on most systemd distros, you should create your custom service files under `/etc/systemd/...` not `/usr/lib/systemd/`; they will be correctly linked when enabled.

Comment: Adding a point to boldsuck's excellent service file answer. (Would add as a comment but don't have the rep on this group yet!) If you're running SELinux in enforcing mode (good for you!), these commands will allow xmrig to run as a service: sudo semanage fcontext -a "/home/USER/xmrig/xmrig" -t bin_t restorecon -rv /home/USER/xmrig Must have the *policycoreutils-python-utils* package